# Codeigniter : data not being inserted in cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data in the cart as follows

```
public function add(){ 
       $this->load->library('cart'); 
        $data = array(
          "id"     => $this->input->post('product_id'),
          "name"   => $this->input->post('product_name'),
          "qty"    => $this->input->post('quantity'), 
          "price"  => $this->input->post('product_price'),
         );
   $this->cart->insert($data);  
 }
```

My javascript code

```
<script>
 $("form").submit(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();


            var product_id = $(this).find('input[name=product_id]').val();
            var quantity = $(this).find('input[name=qty]').val();
            var product_name = $(this).find('h3.title').text();
            var product_price = $(this).find('h3.price').data('price');
            alert(product_price);

            if(quantity != '' && quantity > 0)
              {
               $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart/add",
                method:"POST",
                data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, quantity:quantity},
                success:function(data)
                {
                 alert("Product Added into Cart");
                 $('#cart_details').html(data);
                 $('#' + product_id).val('');
                }
               });
              }
              else
              {
               alert("Please Enter quantity");
              } 

    }); 
});
</script>
```

i get a popup that data inserted in the cart but nothing is there.

```
<?php echo form_open('cart/add_cart_item'); ?>
       <h3 class="text-tamween title"  ><?=$value->title;?></h3>
       <h3 class="text-tamween price" data-price="<?=$value->price?>">Prcie :<?=$value->price;?>AED</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="number" value="<?=$qty?>" class="form-controls qty" min="
         <?=$qty?> "name="qty" >
       </div>
        <p>
          <?=$value->description;?>
         </p>    
       <?php echo form_hidden('product_id', $value->id); ?> 
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add to Cart">
 <?=form_close();?>
```

Comment: The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility. see https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 0):

print:

```
$this->input->post()
```

i think some of the data is missing.

In codeigniter cart library, the first four array indexes above (id, qty, price, and name) are required. If you omit any of them the data will not be saved to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

There is no return on the function. You should return the cart json.

```
public function add() { 
    ...
    $this->cart->insert($data);  

    // Return|Output JSON Data
    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($this->cart->contents()));
}
```